# How to update nested object in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a kanban task management app. So far I've been able to create a task and delete task but I can get my head around how to update a nested task object. I have searched the documentation there's no clear explanation.

I wanted to update the task with the id of 62ff74bfe80b11ade2d34455 - req.params.id with the req.body.

```
{
    "_id": "62fa5aa25778ec97bc6ee231",
    "user": "62f0eb5ebebd0f236abcaf9d",
    "name": "Marketing Plan",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "todo",
            "_id": "62fa5aa25778ec97bc6ee233",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "title": "Task Four",
                    "description": "This is task four",
                    "subtasks": [
                        {
                            "name": "wash dshes",
                            "completed": false,
                            "_id": "62ff74bfe80b11ade2d34456"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "do homework",
                            "completed": false,
                            "_id": "62ff74bfe80b11ade2d34457"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "62ff74bfe80b11ade2d34455"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "doing",
            "_id": "62fa5aa25778ec97bc6ee234",
            "tasks": []
        },
        {
            "name": "done",
            "_id": "62fa5aa25778ec97bc6ee235",
            "tasks": []
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

```
// @desc    Edit task
// @route   PUT /api/tasks/:id
// @access  Private
const editTask = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, subtasks, status } = req.body;

  const task = await Board.findOne({ "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id });

  const taskStatus = await Board.findOne({
    "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id,
    "columns._id": status,
  });

  if (!task) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Task not found");
  }

  // Check for user
  if (!req.user) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }

  // Make sure the logged in user matches the task user
  if (task.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("User not authorized");
  }

  if (taskStatus) {
    const updatedTask = await Board.findOneAndUpdate({
      "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id,
    });
  }


  task.columns.map(async (val) => {
    // check if tasks id equals the status id in the request body
    if (val._id.toString() === status) {
      const updatedTask = await Board.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          "columns.tasks._id": req.params.id,
        },
        { $set: { "columns.$[].tasks": { _id: req.params.id } } },
        { new: true }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently and I couldn't find a way to update it using mongoose. So I have come up with a workaround.

After doing all your checks

```
// retrieve the column index you want to update (I assume you have only these 3 columns)
const columnIndex = _.findIndex(task.columns, { name: "todo" });

// retrieve the actual column object
const column = task.columns[columnIndex ];

// get the index of the specific task you want to update
const taskIndex = _.findIndex(column.tasks, { _id: req.params.id });

// manipulate whatever you want here on the specific task by its index
task.columns[columnIndex].tasks[taskIndex]._id = req.params.id

// then finally you need to update the whole columns array
await Board.updateOne({your query here}, {
  $set: {
    columns: task.columns
  }
});
```

This is actually dirty, but your data is structured in a very difficult way.

I am using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) in the example. you are free to use JavaScript's array methods